# Axios POST to express api gives Request failed

Tags: node.js, react-native, post, axios

I am trying to do a post from my React native app with axios. This is a post to my express api I wrote. The data I am trying to send is correct but I keep getting a 400 error request failed.

My React Native code with the axios request is like this:

```js
postToDatabase = async() => {
    console.log(this.state);
    API.post('/restaurants', {
        name: this.state.name,
        description: this.state.description,
        places_free: this.state.places_free,
        latitude: this.state.latitude,
        longitude: this.state.longitude,
        phone: this.state.phone,
        website: this.state.website
    })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

the express post is like this:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/api/restaurants', (req, res, next) => {
    var errors = [];
    if(!req.query.name){
        errors.push("No name specified");
    }
    if(!req.query.description){
        errors.push("No description specified");
    }
    if(!req.query.places_free){
        errors.push("No description specified");
    }
    if(!req.query.latitude){
        errors.push("No latitude specified");
    }
    if(!req.query.longitude){
        errors.push("No longitude specified");
    }
    if(!req.query.phone){
        errors.push("No phone specified");
    }
    if(!req.query.website){
        errors.push("No website specified");
    }

    if(errors.length){
        res.status(400).json({"error": errors.join(',')});
        return;
    }

    var data = {
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        places_free: req.body.places_free,
        latitude: req.body.latitude,
        longitude: req.body.longitude,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        website: req.body.website
    }

    var sql = "INSERT INTO restaurants (name, description, places_free, latitude, longitude, phone, website) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    var params = [data.name, data.description, data.places_free, data.latitude, data.longitude, data.phone, data.website];
    db.run(sql, params, (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            res.status(400).json({"error": err.message});
            return;
        } else {
            res.json({
                "status" : "succes",
                "data": data
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I was hoping that someone would see where I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be other errors, but the one I found is that you are using `req.query` when you should be using `req.body`.

`req.query` is for query params like `/api/example?foo=bar`, whereas `req.body` is for the body of a request

Comment: You mean in the error checking? I will try to remove them and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, because in your request, req.query won't be populated, but req.body will

Comment: That solved the issue, the rest of the code functioned as expected and the insert happened. Will rewrite the error checking to use req.body